# Make background color change frequently with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, background

I have a link with a background color of bright green and am trying to get the background to change to silver after an interval to produce a flashing effect. Is there a way to do this using CSS as I can not use javascript?

Comment: coding on google sites I suppose

Comment: see "css animation" , fiddle example here http://fiddle.jshell.net/ZH8GN/

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using css like below.

Here is fiddle **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w3Qy9/79/)**

```
<div class="blinkdiv">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@-webkit-keyframes blackWhite {  
  0% { background-color: red; }
  50% { background-color: red; }
  51% { background-color: black; }
  100% { background-color: black; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blackWhiteFade {  
  0% { background-color: red; }
  50% { background-color: black; }
  100% { background-color: red; }
}

.blinkdiv {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
  -webkit-animation-name: blackWhite;
  /* -webkit-animation-name: blackWhiteFade; */
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;  
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; 
}
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.

[***Updated Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/w3Qy9/80/)  as per your requirement

Comment: But remember this you can use it in some of the browsers, which support CSS3 animations. This animation works only in browsers that support - webkit